# Can I download historical CPU usage data for Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Anyone know if there is a way to download historical cpu usage data via API call for Google Compute Engine?

On the Console overview page, graphs are provided for this type of data for at least a month, but I don't see anything obvious on how to download the actual data directly.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Compute Engine [usage export](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export) feature recently launched - it sounds like what you're looking for.  It gives daily detail in a CSV, as well as a month-to-date summary.